# A Question on First Order Exact Differential Equations.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

As I learned , an exact differential equation is given by the following form

$A(x,y)+B(x,y)\frac{dy}{dx}=0$

Following an algebric manipulation it is possible to reach the following :

$A(x,y)dx+B(x,y)dy=0$

The “test” to be sure it it is an exact differential equation is to check the following equality:

$\frac{\partial A}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial B}{\partial x}$

Then to find the solution I need to find a “scalar potential” function U
such that :

$\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}=A,\;\frac{\partial U}{\partial y}=B,$

Then the solutions are $U=C_{(const)}$
(implicit function)

Few things I have trouble to understand.

- As I know about finding a scalar potential of a vector field using

  $-\vec{\nabla}F=U$
  how does that make sense here ? I will appreciate if you can explain in terms of gradient if possible this is the best way for me to understand.
- Say I have a function $U=x^{5}y+7xy^{3}$
  , then the differential of $U$
  will be $dU=(5x^{4}y+7y^{3})dx+(x^{5}+21xy^{2})dy$
  How this differential is different from the Gradient of the function? I feel that it has connection to the topic of exact differential equations, how does this can help me ?

Thanks for the help, I will appreciate if you could explain this to me as simple as possible.

Comment: The difference between gradient and differential is something that does not apply to your case. To convert between one and the other use the following dictionary: $e_i=(0,\ldots 1, \ldots 0) \equiv dx_i$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thanks for your answer, could you please elaborate on the other parts of the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the chain rule, we have that the differential of a potential field is its gradient dotted with the differential displacement:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}U
&= \frac{\partial U}{\partial x} \mathrm{d}x 
  +\frac{\partial U}{\partial y} \mathrm{d}y \\
&= \left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial U}{\partial y} \right) \cdot
   \left( \mathrm{d}x, \mathrm{d}y \right) \\
&= \vec{\nabla} U \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{x}.
\end{align}
$$

So $\vec{\nabla} U$ is the gradient, while $\vec{\nabla} U \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{x}$ is the differential.

For your specific example, the gradient is $(5x^4y+7y^3,x^5+21xy^2)$ while the differential is $(5x^4y+7y^3)\mathrm{d}x+(x^5+21xy^2)\mathrm{d}y$.

Once we find a potential $U$ such that $\frac{\partial U}{\partial x} = A$ and $\frac{\partial U}{\partial y} = B$, then the exact equation

$$ A \,\mathrm{d}x + B \,\mathrm{d}y = 0$$

becomes

$$
\frac{\partial U}{\partial x} \mathrm{d}x 
+\frac{\partial U}{\partial y} \mathrm{d}y = 0
$$

so that $\mathrm{d}U = 0$, from which it follows that $U$ equals a constant.

Comment: Cool, thank you for the answer.Could you please explain me the connection between the first order "exact" differential equation and the potential func. ?

Comment: @user313448 Done.